# Error on Harbor as Docker Hub proxy when "Prevent Vulnerable Images" is enabled

Tags: harbor

I am using Harbor as `Docker Hub Proxy`, where the docker daemon was configure to point for this registry. This part is working ok.
But, I find a problem when I enable the option `"Prevent Vulnerable Images"` following the image below to the "library" project.

https://i.ibb.co/fDZKWN1/harbor.png

If this options is checked, the docker pull command don't work, showing the error below, but if is unchecked, the command work ok.

https://i.ibb.co/D9cMCXQ/error.png

```
- harbor version: v1.8.2 (online)
- docker engine version: 18.06.1-ce
- docker-compose version: 1.24.1
```

Github issue: https://github.com/goharbor/harbor/issues/9094

Answer (score 0):

So far, Harbor does not fully support the registry mirror/proxy function. The good news is registry proxy/mirror is put into the Harbor roadmap now, you can check it [here](https://github.com/goharbor/harbor/blob/master/ROADMAP.md).